# Split 4 Spaces in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a file which consists of lines in the following format:

```
field1    field2    field3
```

Each field is separated by 4 spaces.

I am trying to extract field2 from the above list using Perl.

So, this is what I have done,

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

($input, $output) = @ARGV;

chomp $output;

open(INPUT,"<",$input);
open(OUTPUT,">>",$output);

while(<INPUT>)
{
chomp $_;
($f1,$f2,$f3)= split("\t",$_,3); // *** This line was modified later.
print OUTPUT $f2."\n";
}

close INPUT;
close OUTPUT;
```

This gives me a blank file.

I have tried to modify the line indicated above with an asterisk as:

```
($f1,$f2,$f3)= split("\t",$_);
($f1,$f2,$f3)= split("    ",$_);
($f1,$f2,$f3)= split("\s\s\s\s",$_);
```

In all these cases, again I get an empty file.

Comment: Generally the `\s` character class takes care of most whitespace, you just need to have an operator after it a `+` or a '*'. Try `/\s+/`

Comment: It may be that your `open` statement(s) have failed. You should never use `open` without checking if it failed or not, e.g. `open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!`.

Comment: Make that an answer, @TLP. I'm sure you're right.

Comment: @ikegami Done. It seemed a bit simplistic, but then I saw he was not using warnings.

Comment: Agree with @TLP.  OP Also didn't specify whether he was splitting on the actual space character or any whitespace, though `/\s{4}/` would work either way.

Comment: Everything in the code was correct here. But in my actual code, the output file handle had a different name than the one to which I was writing. use warnings helped. Thanks. I am using this now, split(/\s{4}/,$_);

Comment: Unless you have a reason to care about the *amount* of whitespace separating the fields, just use `split(' ', $_)` ( or `split` ). A string consisting of a single space is special-cased to split on any amount of whitespace, like `awk`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be that your open statement(s) have failed. You should never use open without checking if it failed or not, e.g.

```
open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;
```

I used three argument open with a lexical file handle, as is recommended. See [perldoc -f open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) for more information.

Such a mistake will be revealed if you are using `use warnings`, giving an error:

```
readline() on closed filehandle INPUT at ...
```

However, if you are not using warnings, the error will be silent and deadly. It goes without saying that you should of course always

```
use warnings;
use strict;
```

Comment: Sweet and Simple. Thank you. The problem was with the Output File Handle, I was printing into a different handle which was not opened. use warnings helped.

Comment: @NeonFlash You're welcome. You should also use the strict pragma, it will help you avoid many other common mistakes, such as typos.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works if the fields are separated by four spaces as you claim.

```
$ echo 'field1    field2    field3' | perl -nlE'say for split "    ";'
field1
field2
field3
```

Verify that your file actually four spaces contains using `od -c`.

---

Btw, you're lying to yourself by using `split "..."` instead of `split /.../`. The first arg of [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) is a regular expression. It's clearer if you make it look like one.